# What's the best way to create an XML placeholder string in obj-c

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I basically want to define an XML string in my header ie:

```
#define kXMLString "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xml>%@</xml>"
```

In in my code I then want to replace the placeholders ie:

```
NSString *xmlpMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:kXMLString, @"value"];
```

However this gives me warnings/errors. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Ok I think I managed to fix this, I have to put this in the .m (not .h) file, just under any #import's and above @implementatiion

NSString * const kXMLString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xml>%@</xml>";

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the @:

```
#define kXMLString @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xml>%@</xml>"
```

or better:

```
const NSString *kXMLString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xml>%@</xml>";
```

Comment: Sorry I did put the @ but somehow missed it in the question.

What you suggested still doesn't work, the NSString version expects paramaters at the end but I don't want to use paramters yet, I want to add the paramaters in another part of the code.